# rosmake sbpl_interface - problem with missing dependency

Tags: moveit, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would be happy for any commentary or answer.
If I expressed myself unclear, please tell me.

**Background**: the package `sbpl_interface` requires the `collision_distance_field`-package as a dependency.

**Approach**: The package `collision_distance_field`is located inside of the moveit_core package.
Due there is a package.xml file in it I put the whole MoveIt!_source-folder in my catkin_worspace under /src.
After catkin_make was successful, the package `collision_distance_field` is still missing:

```
faps@faps-Aspire-5740D:~/catkin_ws/src$ rosmake sbpl_interface
  .................
  [rosbuild] Building package sbpl_interface
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack deps-manifests sbpl_interface
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'sbpl_interface' depends on non-existent package 'collision_distance_field' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'sbpl_interface'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package sbpl_interface written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/faps/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130430-014403/sbpl_interface/build_output.log
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< sbpl_interface [FAIL] [ 0.88 seconds ]                 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package sbpl_interface. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 39 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/faps/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130430-014403
```

**Info:** `rosdep update` also fails.

**Questions**:

1. How can I fix the missing dependency?
2. I've allready installed
   MoveIt!-Full via `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-moveit-full`, shouldn't moveit_core with all contained packages already be installed?

Many Thanks in advance
rosrookie

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61601/rosmake-sbpl_interface---problem-with-missing-dependency/) by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi rosrookie,

Thanks for giving MoveIt! a try. Unfortunately, sbpl_interface has not been fully ported to the latest version of MoveIt! yet which is why its not working. The authors are working on updating it right now and we'll let you know as soon as its fully up and running.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0